# StoreKit: Catch failed restore?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm implementing In-App purchase feature with **Restore** button.

I have a **brand new test user** set up, without any payments made.

When I hit the restore button, and log in with the new test user, I cannot catch any delegated methods that tell me that the **restoring transaction has failed** (since there is nothing to restore).

The only method that get invoked is `-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue`, but this method gets called in the case when restoring was successful too.

What can I do now? How can I catch such a case?

---

Addition: I have a progress indicator that says "Contacting App Store", and I need an invocation where I can hide it in failed cases too.

Comment: Since the issue was not purchased by the Test user, you won't get `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` in reply from the iTunesConnect,which ultimately finishes your transcation.

Comment: Thats clear. But I showed up a "Contacting App Store" progress indicator, and I still need an event to hide it on failure too.

Comment: there is no failure, when no transactions are there to restore. Actually this case is handled as success.

Comment: Then hide your indicator in `-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue` method

Comment: Yeah, something similar. I count the queue.transactions array, then if its return zero, I delegate failure.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing too now. Thanks.

Comment: How did you do that? could you put in your code? Thanks ;D

Comment: @Geri how was your solution? could you post it below your awnser?

Answer (score 9):

Noah: here's a code snippet for you:

```
-(void)restore {

    [self.delegate showLoadingScreen];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];


}
```

And the following method:

```
-(void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue {

    if (!queue.transactions || [queue.transactions count] == 0) {

        [self showAlertScreenWithTitle:@"Error Restoring Subscription" message:@"No subscription was found to restore."];

    } else {

        BOOL didRestore = NO;

        for (SKPaymentTransaction *t in queue.transactions) {

            if (t.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored || t.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {

                NSTimeInterval now = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - _timeOffset;
                NSTimeInterval expire = [t.transactionDate timeIntervalSince1970] + kExplorerSubscriptionSecondLength;
                NSTimeInterval purchase = [t.transactionDate timeIntervalSince1970];

                if (purchase <= now && now <= expire) {

                    didRestore = YES;
                }

            }


        }

        if (!didRestore)
            [self showAlertScreenWithTitle:@"Error Restoring Subscription" message:@"No subscription was found to restore."];

    }    

    [self.delegate dismissLoadingScreen];

}
```

Let me know if that helps you....

Comment: thx, solved...with this line :D (!queue.transactions || [queue.transactions count] == 0)

Comment: i still found i needed the else statement. but i remember now in what situation... if a user has a subscription that has expired, and you try to restore, it will still return the previous purchases for each month the user was subscribed. that's why i check the time period. if "now" doesn't fall within any of the time periods, nothing was restored. this might not apply to your situation

Answer (score 1):

When you restore a transactions, there're two delegated methods:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
```

The first one (**paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished**) is called when all the transactions are restored. If you don't have any previous purchase it also calls this method because the restored worked fine but there's nothing to restore.

The other method (**restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError**) is called when there's an error restoring the transaction.

If you need to show a message to the user telling him he doesn't have any transaction to restore you can use:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
```

Here you have a small snippet for this delegate:

```
//
// called when the transaction status is updated
//
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                restoredTransaction++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use the **restoredTransaction** variable to know if any transaction has been restored on **paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished**

Comment: But how did Geri solved this problem? He says that he solved it with returning 0 which is returned from the NSLog if there are no purchases made before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following delegate method for Restore Transaction.

```
 -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"Error when purchasing: %@",error);

}
```

Comment: that delegate is only called if the restore was canceled or there was an internet connection error. I want if the user hasn't made any purchases before and thats the problem. Take a look at the comments of the question. There is a solutin with returning a value but I don't know how.