# In-App purchase Thank You! Alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have app A with product X that has been set up years ago. Then I have app B with product Y that has been set up recently. I now notice the following:

```
iOS 6/app A/product X : after purchase app store provides "Thank You" alert
iOS 5/app A/product X : no alert
iOS 6/app B/product Y : no alert
iOS 5/app B/product Y : no alert
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here? The purchasing code in both apps is identical.

Comment: I got this issue in iOS 5 too

Comment: CReatTus: can you give specific scenario and describe what happens to you?

Comment: could you take a look at this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754900/storekit-catch-failed-restore/14253062#14253062